# Use tweepy search API. But get much fewer result than I search on the website. Why?

Tags: python, api, search, twitter, tweepy

```
for result in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q = "www.nature.com", count = 100).items():
    count = count + 1
print count
```

There's only 11 results by using tweepy search API. But when I search at https://twitter.com/search, it returns much more results! Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitter API search only goes a couple of days back. It's different to the one used on the website.

Comment: I believe that it is now also possible to search historical tweets using the API.